# How to store the data in coredata iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am working in the iPhone messaging app. Am `using coredata to store the messages(Sent by the user and received from the webservice), username, date and time`. I want to save the username once and add the send/received messages and date to the corresponding username.

Like this way:

```
No   Name        Date                ReceivedMessage        SendMessage
1    Gopinath    27 june, 12.01pm    Hi                     ----
                 27 june, 12.02pm    ----                   Hello

2    ABCD        26 june, 1.01pm     Hi                     ----
                 26 june, 2.02pm     ----                   Hello
                 27 june, 8pm        Hi Gopi                ----
```

Received messages should be store when i receive from service and Sendmessage will be stored when the user composed and send the message.

Can anyone please help me how to store the data like this using CoreData in my project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an entity with the following attributes:

```
Message
- mid: uint // message ID
- name: string
- date: date
- sent: boolean
- message: string
```

And Messages are created with:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Message" inManagedObjectContext: context]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by most of the CoreData tutorials you can find on the net. It seems you could do this with one table.

Just follow a tutorial like this:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Also, fabrice also did a quick example on what your table could look like.

You won't find complete code examples here.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a general question.

You could do it in one entity, but do it correctly from the start. Create a User entity and a Message entity. Create a relationship, one user has many messages, between them. It will save you refactoring later when you decide you want to store more data about the user. With one entity, you will be duplicating data.

Read about normalising database tables.

Read the core data programming guide.

When you have a more specific question, you'll get plenty of help here.